# Getting 500(internal server) error in production environment

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

I have an issue in the production server.

In my application there are so many jQuery-AJAX post call, so for handling timeout error i used following code in the error block:

```
        if (result.status == '401') {
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            alert("Failed to process");
            location.reload();
        }
```

If error status is 401,page gets refreshed and automatically redirect to log-in page.Its working perfectly in my local machine but when i deployed in the production server the 401 error changes to 500(internal server) error status.

Do anyone have any idea to resolve the same, if it 500 error status.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: 500 error indicates scripting or server side error.. you need to bug it out.

Comment: Its came when time out happened in the production. But 401 in local machine.

Comment: which is the scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of trying to catch the error at client side  i.e in jquery error should be checked in logger in server side.You may check few other parameter like GET or POST used in jquery script as well as in server side. Return type used in json and return type mentioned in serverside code.

Comment: Then what will happen?